# Is "content-hash" a mandatory part of composer.lock?

Tags: composer-php

Like most people writing (and reading) the question about [whether to keep `composer.lock` in version-control](/questions/12896780/should-composer-lock-be-committed-to-version-control), we keep ours there.

However, this causes us trouble every time the file is independently updated in different code-branches. Even when the changes are unrelated and affect the sections of the file afar from each other, the `"content-hash"` line is causing a conflict *every time*. Worse, neither "side" is correct and whoever is doing the merging must regenerate the file by hand...

Maybe, the line is not really necessary? Before asking, whether (the current version of) composer will work without it, what functionality would be missing? The hash seems to guard against the file itself changing -- but the source-control system is already doing that...

Can I simply remove the line? If it can not be done today, would it be a desirable feature for composer?

Comment: Ha, nice to see you here, Mikhail!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

### Purpose of the content hash

As you can see in [`Composer\Package\Locker::getContentHash()`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1.5.2/src/Composer/Package/Locker.php#L65-L102), the content hash takes into account the following fields of `composer.json`:

```
$relevantKeys = array(
    'name',
    'version',
    'require',
    'require-dev',
    'conflict',
    'replace',
    'provide',
    'minimum-stability',
    'prefer-stable',
    'repositories',
    'extra',
);
```

The only reason for the content hash to change is a change of one of the values of the corresponding properties in `composer.json`.

Composer uses the content hash to determine whether relevant fields in `composer.json` are in sync with `composer.lock`. You can run

```
$ composer validate
```

to find out if they are in sync.

If `composer.json` and `composer.lock` are not in sync, a message similar to this will be shown

> The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json, it is recommended that you run `composer update`.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#validate:

> You should always run the validate command before you commit your `composer.json` file, and before you tag a release. It will check if your `composer.json` is valid.

### Resolving conflicts in `composer.lock`

If you have trouble resolving conflicts in `composer.lock`, maybe this helps:

#### Step 1: Accept upstream changes

Usually, you will probably attempt to rebase a branch on top of the upstream changes. When already in conflict, use your IDE, or run

```
$ git checkout --theirs composer.lock
```

to accept the upstream changes to `composer.lock`. Since this is a generated file, you really don't want to resolve conflicts in it.

#### Step 2: Re-apply changes to `composer.json` and `composer.lock`

As pointed out earlier, there are a range of the relevant keys in `composer.json`. Some of them can be modified by corresponding commands, others cannot.

For example, if one of the changes is a newly added or removed package, run

```
$ composer require foo/bar:^1.2.3
```

or

```
$ composer remove foo/bar
```

to apply the changes.

If the changes cannot be applied by running a command, manually modify `composer.json`, then run

```
$ composer update --lock
```

This will update the content hash.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update:

> **--lock**: Only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer would seem to suggest, the `composer.lock` should _not_ after all be checked into source control -- because it is an artefact, rather than a human-coded file...

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, of course. For applications, I would always want to check in `composer.lock`. This ensures that running `composer install` installs the exact same dependencies every time, in every environment (unless platform requirements aren't satisfied, then nothing will be installed. Not checking in `composer.lock` and running `composer install` has the same effect as running `composer update` (assuming that no `composer.lock` already exists). This might have undesired consequences, as different versions of packages could be installed.

Comment: For libraries, you can check in `composer.lock`, but generally, you want to ensure that the library works with a range of versions, rather than the versions currently pinned to. Then you usually run builds against the lowest and highest versions. If you then check in `composer.lock`, you can also run a build against the set of versions pinned to in `composer.lock`.

Comment: Is that check/assurance even meaningful, unless you are also locking down the versions of the OS kernel, `libc`, the php, and the C-compiler used to compile php (and all of its extensions)? But I'm not arguing against the _use_ of the `composer.lock` -- only against checking it into source-control... It would be generated during build instead...

Comment: The platform requirements can also be specified in `composer.json`, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#platform-packages. Again, not checking in `composer.json` comes with the risk of pulling in breaking changes. That can (and has happened at Refinery29), even when using sane version requirements, and even when package maintainers *claim* to follow semantic versioning (see http://semver.org).

Comment: It would seem, the requirements weren't properly specified in `composer.json` -- which should be checked-in. But the `composer.lock`, which is derived from it, no... Of course, accidents have -- and will continue to -- happen...

Comment: Absolutely, they will!

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR version from @localheinz:

Just resolve the conflict and then regenerate the lock file with:

```
$ composer update --lock
```

This will update the content hash.

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update:

> **--lock**: Only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date.

Comment: "Why tho?" -- is the question. Why have the hash there in the first place? If, as you suggest, one is to just regenerate it, why have it at all -- and deal with the constant merge-conflicts requiring manual interventions? If it is not mandatory, I think, it should simply be removed. If it is mandatory, it should become optional...

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. Yes it is not an overthought feature which makes no sense.